# Where does "Do you want the bill grabbing?" come from?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, dialects, variants, british-english

I heard this phrase at a restaurant the other day - in Sheffield, England. The waitress said first, "Do you want anything else getting?", and then after that, "Do you want the bill grabbing?"

This sounds like a very strange form of the passive to me, as if it's using the progressive -ing instead of the passive participle -ed. I guess the standard sentence would be "Do you want the bill to be grabbed" if you wanted to coerce it into the passive, although "Do you want me to grab the bill" sounds far more natural.

Where does this phrasing comes from? Does it belong to a particular Northern dialect? I've never heard it in Sheffield or anywhere else before. Also, what's going on syntactically in this sentence?

Comment: Was the waitress a native speaker? --that's a very German sort of phrasing, with the *-ing* form for the infinitive.

Comment: Yeah, she had a Northern accent. Not sure if Sheffield or not.

Comment: You can't just interview her?

Comment: @aparente001 I doubt if 'interviewing' her would help, unless she has studied the grammar of her local dialect. Of course she may have, but most of us don't. It's a construction I use (probably picked up from my parents, who hail from another Northern English town, but I don't know why where it originated.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know how socially acceptable it is to walk into a bar/restaurant and go "Hey, lady who served me two days ago, can I interrogate you on your use of the English language?" With willing research participants, yeah I'd ask them directly about it, but I'd prefer to leave this one to the anonymous diagnostics of the internet.

Comment: Leo - I didn't mean a formal interview.  It's just a matter of going back to the bar/restaurant and being friendly, so you can strike up a conversation.  That's all I meant.  @Spagirl - It sounds like you have the local dialect and the level of sophistication to help.  I hope you can check in with relatives/friends and get some ideas.  The expression sounds so strange to my ear.  Perhaps you could at least list some similar phrases to get the ball rolling here.

Comment: @aparente001 As I say, *using* a construction doesn't equal knowing why  TBH I was only very dimly aware that this was non-standard. I think the particular set-up Leo asks about is confined to questions. I might say 'I'm off to Tesco, is there anything you want fetching?', or 'I feel like baking, is there anything you want making?'.  Would a sentence like 'The grass needs cutting' or 'those papers want filing' sound strange to you as well?

Comment: @Spagirl - Thanks!  Those sound totally fine to me, actually.  But that *grabbing* still sounds so weird to me.  Anyway, I think what you put in your comment should go into an answer, albeit a partial answer, since comments are ephemeral.